# Calling CanadaPost from NetSuite Client

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to call the Canada Post API directly from the NetSuite client in order to get the shipping rates.

This is the test code for devlopment:

```
var url = 'https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/price';
var auth = 'Basic BASE64ENCODEDUSERNAMEANDPASSWORD';
var xml = '' +
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<mailing-scenario xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/ship/rate-v3">' +
'<customer-number>1234567</customer-number>' +
'<parcel-characteristics><weight>1.0</weight></parcel-characteristics>' +
'<services><service-code>DOM.XP</service-code></services>' +
'<origin-postal-code>K2B8J6</origin-postal-code>' +
'<destination><domestic><postal-code>J0E1X0</postal-code></domestic></destination>' +
'</mailing-scenario>';

var header = {
    'Authorization': auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml;application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml',
    'Accept-language': 'en-CA',
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml'
};

var r = nlapiRequestURL(url, xml, header, null, 'POST');

console.log(r.code[0]);
console.log(r.body);
```

The instructions are pretty clear and the XML format seems to be right, but I keep getting the same response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/messages">
<message>
<code>400</code>
<description>Backend Bad Request</description></message></messages>
```

Any clue?

Reference:
https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/rating/getrates/default.jsf

*Edit: I've tried using also  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml' and I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/messages">
<message>
<code>415</code>
<description>Backend Unsupported Media Type</description></message></messages>
```

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is your Content-Type header is wrong. You can't actually mix content types like that. The CP website indicates it wants

```
Content-Type: "application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml"
```

Your problem is going to be that NS explicitly states that they will only respect certain content-type values:

> Also note that if you call nlapiRequestURL, passing in the header with a content type, NetSuite respects the following types:
>   
>   all text media types (types starting with "text/")
>   "application/json"
>   "application/vnd.maxmind.com-country+json"
>   "application/xml"
>   "application/soap+xml"
>   "application/xhtml+xml"
>   "application/atom+xml"
>   Otherwise, NetSuite will overwrite the content type with our default type as if the type had not been specified. NetSuite default types are:
>   
>   "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

What I would do would be to test whether CP lets you get away with Content-Type : "text/xml" or "application/xml"

If not I'd file a case with both CP and NS in hopes that either CP would allow the more generic type or NS would allow a specific type. Don't hold your breath.

what I have actually done to solve this sort of thing is to just proxy the request through a system that I have control of. It's pretty easy to write a small app that will receive the request; reset the headers properly and forward the request.

Comment: Tried changing the content type and it gives me a "Backend Unsupported Media Type" error. 

The script is currently running through a PHP proxy to handle credentials, but we want to refactor to run directly from client.

Comment: I'd first go the tech support with Canada Post. There's no good reason for their very specific content type requirement. There's  no good reason for Netsuite's restrictions either but good luck there.

Comment: Lol... I typed the exact same question and the beauty that is StackOverflow & Joel Spoelsky is amazing... it brought me right here...

Ive already submitted a request to the Canada Post Technical Department & I will POST (pun intended) the answer as soon as they get back to me because you know I want those upvotes!!! LOL